# java selenium - how to apply or add a <br> tab in the webpage and execute

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, html

From the webpage i want to add a `<br>` tag in the particular section
below is the html code

```
<p style="font-size:13pt; line-height:130%; margin:0pt; orphans:0; text-align:center; widows:0"> <span class="notranslate" onmouseover="_tipon(this)" onmouseout="_tipoff()"><span class="src-text" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left"><span style="font-family:????; font-size:13pt">?????</span></span> <span style="font-family:????; font-size:13pt">content</span></span> </p>
```

from the above i want to add one `<br>` tag after `</p>`

used javascript executor
but its failed

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("/html/body/div[1]/br");
```

Comment: Are you trying to save and  pass the link's html with an additional `<br> `?

Comment: from the webpage add a br tag in the particular section then execute and save the source of the webpage

Comment: What do you mean by "save the source of the webpage"?

Comment: Once adding the br tag i will collect the source and stored in seperate txt file.String source = driver.getPageSource();

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the parent element of "p" element and append a child 
 to the parent. For example:

```
<div id='mydiv'>
     <p>.............</p>
</div>
```

So, for adding a line break to it, refer :

```
JavascriptExecutor js;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('mydiv').insertBefore(document.createElement('br'), document.getElementsByTagName('p');");
```

Comment: element don't have a ID attribute so i'm using always xpath

Answer (score 0):

Try if this resolves your issue :

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
 WebElement pelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/p "));

 js.executeScript("arguments[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br>');", pelement);
```